# Can I print UTF-8 encoded files from Linux command-line?

Tags: linux, utf-8, printing, terminal

`enscript` doesn't support utf-8 and the only other suggestion I've seen is to use `lpr`:

```
lpr -o document-format=text/utf8 file_to_print
```

but that gives an "Unsupported format" error.

(Ubuntu 9.04 / GNOME Terminal 2.26.0)

Answer (score 1):

what about converting to post script and then printing PS directly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`paps`](http://paps.sourceforge.net/) to convert UTF-8 input to postscript.  A bit crude but it seems to get the job done, at least for Latin-1 glyphs.